# How to dynamically change the spreadsheet of a Google site page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I've checked [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=572) and now I know (with getHtmlContent and setHtmlContent) how to create a webapp that :

a) takes into account the active user id

b) selects accordingly the right spreadsheet to be displaid

c) adapts a Google site page with the selected spreadsheet

But my problem is that I want to dynamically adapt the page when the user clicks the link to it (from navigation area). How can I trigger my webapp ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to invoke scripts from links in the Navigation area. But it is definitely possible to invoke an Apps Script on a link in the content area of a Google Sites page.

You can consider invoking your script from such a link

Comment: Thanks Srik.
But it still means 2 steps before loading the desired spreadsheet on my page ...